# Сделать свечение только у индикатора в progress bar wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Я делаю свечение через DropShadowEffect. Если тупо повесить его на прогресс бар, свечение будет на всем прогресс баре. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы свечение было только на индикаторе(то есть сама эта штука, которая двигается и показывает проценты). Если нажать ПКМ прогресс бару и нажать на правка шаблона, то там будет все то, из чего состоит прогресс бар[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал добавить свечение и на Indicator, и на Animation - не работает. А если добавить эффект на сам PART_Indicator, то будет вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не описывайте код словами! Давайте пример, скриншоты и все, что необходимо для того, что бы нам понять вашу проблему. Сейчас могу предположить, что у вас идет `<элемент с тенью><другие элементы/></элемент с тенью>`, а должно быть `<grid><элемент><другие элементы></элемент><элемент с тенью/></grid>`, то есть тень отдельно идет от основного контента.

Comment: Добавил скриншоты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без понятия, что у вас там не работает, сделал простенький стиль и вроде все так, как вы хотите:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFAD16"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#303030"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Border CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Name="PART_Track"/>
                        <Decorator x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}" >
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="#FFD10000" BlurRadius="50" />
                                </Border.Effect>
                            </Border>
                        </Decorator>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Пояснения что тут:

- Задаем стартовые значения (цвета, размер, скругление).
- Далее переопределяем сам вид элемента:

  - Первым идет основной `Border`, который просто делает нам задний фон с закругленными углами.

    - Внутри этого `Border`'a расположен `PART_Track` - объект, который определяет путь индикатора.
    - Также тут сам индикатор (`PART_Indicator`)

      - Внутри индикатора располагается `Border`, который как и фон, имеет цвет и закругление, а также нужную нам тень.

В итоге получаем это:

[image: Result]

Как видите у нас только индикатор имеет красноватую тень, все остальное не затрагивается.