# Стиль закругленного ProgressBar. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Суть проблемы вот в чем:
Есть прогрессбар, которому нужно скруглить углы (BorderRadius 15). Впринципе я то решение нашел, но оно не подходит т.к при запуске приложения в VS в Output вылетает исключение:

System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'VisualBrush' (HashCode=64935954); target property is 'Visual' (type 'Visual')

```
<Style x:Key="ProgressBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=MaskBorder}"/>
                            </Grid.OpacityMask>

                            <Border x:Name="MaskBorder" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    CornerRadius="15"/>

                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track"/>

                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Indicator" 
                                  ClipToBounds="true" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" 
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                           RadiusX="15" 
                                           RadiusY="15"/>

                                <Rectangle x:Name="Animation" 
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                                           RadiusX="15" 
                                           RadiusY="15"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3D475B "/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF24AFB2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
```

VisualBrush применил здесь для того что бы срезать выпирающий за границы Border индикатор. Подскажите пожалуйста, как либо убрать исключение либо другим способом скрыть выпирающий индикатор?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ProgressBar с закругленными краями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1187433/progressbar-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid.OpacityMask>
   <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding  Source={x:Reference Name=MaskBorder}}"/>
</Grid.OpacityMask>
```

Вот решение, если кому надо будет.

Comment: Вы точно заметили ссылку, которую я вам дал? Вам просто надо было сделать так, чтобы бордер был на уровень выше, чем элемент, к которому применяется `OpacityMask`. Вот еще [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1076429/373567). А `x:Reference` - это костыль, который к тому же может в некоторых случаях не сработать.